# Establishing monitoring on nine Dell UPS that do not have management cards

Tags: dell, ups

**Goal**  - Establish monitoring on nine Dell UPS that do not have management cards.

•   Dell UPS 1000W x 8
•   Dell UPS 3750W x 1

Is it possible to daisy chain the USB  or Serial (RS-232) ports on Dell UPS?  Trying to get monitoring via Dell UPS Management Software setup on eight Dell UPS 1000Ws and one Dell UPS 3750W.  The eight UPS are racked together, but none of them have a management card installed.  I am trying to figure out if it is possible to daisy chain the USB or Serial ports, or do I need to connect each UPS to its own USB or Serial port on a server/PC?

Comment: What about a USB hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB and Serial connections don't support daisy chaining on any hardware without some kind of hub. A cheap USB hub or serial port concentrator connected to the monitoring PC would work fine.

Alternatively, you could always purchase and install the management cards yourself. Might be worth the investment as they would then be network accessible to any PC.